# Execution output to text file

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, output-redirect

I am writing a C program using Visual Studio 2008. I use F7 to compile and F5 to execute the program.When I press F5 an execution window contains the output. But I want the output to get saved to a text file. How to do this in visual studio. Please help me someone.

Comment: Redirecting the output as described below works just fine but then you don't see any output when running the program - it gets redirected to the file. Consider modifying your code for a logging API, or google for "windows tee"

Answer (score 1):

I think using the command line parameter >*output path* will do the trick. for example:

```
myapp.exe >D:\result.txt
```

will direct the app output to result.txt file. If you running the application from within Visual Studio, you can configure the command line parameters using "project properties > Debug".

Answer (score 0):

You can run the same executable from the command line and redirect its output to a file as:

```
C:\dir_of_the_executable> myprogram.exe > output.txt
```