# Windows find command results to a file

Tags: windows, command, command-prompt, dos

Does anybody know if its possible and if so how to output the results of the windows find command to a text file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execution output to text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656951/execution-output-to-text-file)

Comment: Please search SO before posting questions. This has been asked a multiple of times.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko flag it, and moderators will take care of it

Comment: Apologies if it has, I did search for quiet a while before asking, I don't know how to delete questions on StackOverflow after asking them so I am not sure how to remove it if having it here is causing confusion or annoying anybody, on the bright side, it might even help somebody in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure i understand what you mean but you can redirect the output of any shell command to a file using the > and >> symbols.

like:

```
dir > 1.txt
```

this will write the output of the dir command to the text file 1.txt without showing this on the console.

Comment: This is the idea, this worked for me: find /i "word_to_search_for" file_to_search_in.txt > results_output_file.txt

Answer (score 2):

By using the principle of [Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)

**EXAMPLE:**

> echo "content_to_add_to_text_file" > toto.txt